# Smooth vector field over $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I am a beginner at manifolds. I am trying the following problem:

Let $A=(U_N, \phi _N=(x^1)),(U_S, \phi_S=(x^2))$ be the atlas for $S^1$ with stereographic projection. Define a map as $v(p)= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}|_p$ when $p\neq N$ and  $v(p)= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}|_p$ when $p=N$. Find whether this is a smooth vector field on $S^1$ or not.

My attempt:

I saw the following proposition from Loring tu which says:

Let $(U,\phi)=(U,x^1,\cdot \cdot \cdot, x^n)$ be a chart on a manifold $M$. A vector field $X= \sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ on $U$ is smooth if and only if the coefficient functions $a^i$ are all smooth on $U$.

I am wondering if I can use this theorem or not, if yes then how can I write my given function first into summation form.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what you need to use. Can you see why your vector field is smooth at $\mathbb S^1\setminus \{N\}$?

Comment: @ArcticChar yes, because the coefficient is 1.

Comment: But how to do it on the whole $s^1$?

Comment: You don't do it on the whole $\mathbb S^1$, you check it on each chart. Now you need to write your vector field as $v = b \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$ and check if $b$ is a smooth function.

Comment: On $S^1 - \{N\}$ vector field is $v=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ so b=1. Which is smooth as being constant.

Comment: Yeah, but that does not help you check if your vector field is smooth in a neighborhood of $N$. You need write it as $b \frac{\partial }{\partial x_2}$.

Comment: @ArcticChar, I did not get it. Could you please explain further?

Comment: I am using your definition. $v$ is a vector field on $\mathbb S^1$, in particular it is a vector field on the chart $(U_S, x^2)$. In this chart you can write $v$ as $v = b \frac{\partial }{\partial x^2}$ (it is just your $\sum_i a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$, but without the summation since the dimension is one). Then $v$ is smooth iff $b$ is smooth.

Comment: @ArcticChar, so here $b=0$ if $p \neq N$ and $b=1$ if $p=N$. Hence $b$ is not smooth. Am I making sense?

Comment: You are confusing yourself with the notations (unfortunately). In your notation, $(x^1, x^2)$ is not a local chart, so your vector fields is not really locally of the form  $a_1 \frac{\partial }{\partial x^1} + a_2 \frac{\partial }{\partial x^2}$ (that's why in my previous comment I used $y^i$ instead). In your situation, $(x^1)$ is one local coordinates, $(x^2)$ is another.

Comment: It is better to write $x = x_1$ and $y = x_2$ if you ask me.

Comment: You want to convert from the $x_1$ coordinate system to the $x_2$ coordinate system and find the function $b(x_2)$ such that $\frac\partial{\partial x_1} = b(x_2)\frac\partial{\partial x_2}$

Comment: @AmejiB. , I did not get how to convert

Comment: Okay I think I got some idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to figure out how to change between the two coordinate charts  $x_1$ and $x_2$. Let $(y,z)$ be a point on the unit circle $y^2+z^2=1$. Using triangle ratios, you can find $x_1 = \dfrac y{1-z}$ and $x_2 = \dfrac y{1+z}$. Then $x_1x_2 = \dfrac{y^2}{1-z^2} = 1$, since $y^2+z^2=1$. Thus, whenever both $x_1,x_2$ are both defined, $x_1x_2 = 1$.

Now we want to get $\dfrac\partial{\partial x_1}$ in terms of $x_2$. By the chain rule, this is $\dfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2}\dfrac\partial{\partial x_2}$. Then using $x_1 = \dfrac1{x_2}$, $\dfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2} = \dfrac{-1}{x_2^2}$. Thus $\dfrac\partial{\partial x_1} = \dfrac{-1}{x_2^2}\dfrac\partial{\partial x_2}$. The point $N$ corresponds to $x_2 = 0$, so we see that this quantity is diverging. So no, the vector field is not smooth.